# calling a function in another class from nib/xib file returns "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil" when didSelectRow atIndex (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib, subview

I've been struggling with a strange problem for a few days now. So I have a nib file displaying a programmatically made tableview perfectly inside my storyboard.
The tableview is programmatically made inside the nib file and when I call tableview didSelectRow atIndex, inside it, I call another custom function from the original view controller (`Home`) like below:

```
// This xib file is called ReceiptPage
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            Home().showList(date: date[indexPath.row])
        }
```

This works perfectly until here. Here is my code that crashes in the `Home` view controller:

```
func showList(date:String) {
        print(date) // successfully prints the date as a string
        // code fails from the next line
        self.view.addSubview(shoppingList)

        shoppingList.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y - 35)
        shoppingList.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        shoppingList.alpha = 0
        NSLog("12")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            NSLog("1")
            self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
            self.shoppingList.alpha = 1
            self.shoppingList.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 98/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            self.shoppingList.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.shoppingList.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            self.visualEffectView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

But when I call the same exact code in `viewDidLoad` in `Home` as shown below, it all goes well:

```
self.view.addSubview(shoppingList)

        shoppingList.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y - 35)
        shoppingList.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        shoppingList.alpha = 0
        NSLog("12")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            NSLog("1")
            self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
            self.shoppingList.alpha = 1
            self.shoppingList.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 98/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            self.shoppingList.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.shoppingList.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            self.visualEffectView.isHidden = false
        }
```

I have tried to get around by using a trick but I still failed. Basically, since I am able to pass data that is related to the selected cell to the `Home` view controller, I decided to create a Bool variable and every time a cell is selected, the Bool value turns to true. Then in viewDidAppear, I call the function like this:

```
var selected = Bool()
    func showList(date:String) {
    self.selected = true
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if self.selected == true {
        self.selected = false
        self.view.addSubview(shoppingList)

        shoppingList.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y - 35)
        shoppingList.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        shoppingList.alpha = 0
        NSLog("12")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            NSLog("1")
            self.visualEffectView.effect = self.effect
            self.shoppingList.alpha = 1
            self.shoppingList.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 98/255, blue: 246/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            self.shoppingList.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            self.shoppingList.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            self.visualEffectView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

In response to this code, I get the following message in my debugger:

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
(Function)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I am very confused to why this is happening. Overall, what I am trying to achieve is to change the alpha value of `shoppingList` when a row is selected from the nib file and add it to the other view controller's subview.

I would also appreciate if someone could tell me exactly how to find an error when I get unexpectedly found nil as this has been something I've been long struggling with. No matter if I use breakpoints in the debug navigator or not, I always get this error in this example:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never:
    0x101065184 <+0>:   stp    x26, x25, [sp, #-80]!
    0x101065188 <+4>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #16]
    0x10106518c <+8>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #32]
    0x101065190 <+12>:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #48]
    0x101065194 <+16>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #64]
    0x101065198 <+20>:  add    x29, sp, #64              ; =64 
    0x10106519c <+24>:  mov    x19, x6
    0x1010651a0 <+28>:  mov    x20, x5
    0x1010651a4 <+32>:  mov    x21, x4
    0x1010651a8 <+36>:  mov    x22, x3
    0x1010651ac <+40>:  mov    x23, x2
    0x1010651b0 <+44>:  mov    x24, x1
    0x1010651b4 <+48>:  mov    x25, x0
    0x1010651b8 <+52>:  adr    x8, #936936               ; protocol descriptor for Swift.CVarArg + 88
    0x1010651bc <+56>:  nop    
    0x1010651c0 <+60>:  add    x0, x8, #16               ; =16 
    0x1010651c4 <+64>:  movz   w1, #0x28
    0x1010651c8 <+68>:  orr    w2, wzr, #0x7
    0x1010651cc <+72>:  bl     0x1010654b0               ; rt_swift_allocObject
    0x1010651d0 <+76>:  mov    x8, x0
    0x1010651d4 <+80>:  stp    x22, x21, [x8, #16]
    0x1010651d8 <+84>:  strb   w20, [x8, #32]
    0x1010651dc <+88>:  str    w19, [x8, #36]
    0x1010651e0 <+92>:  adr    x3, #241008               ; partial apply forwarder for Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt, flags : Swift.UInt32) -> Swift.Never).(closure #2)
    0x1010651e4 <+96>:  nop    
    0x1010651e8 <+100>: mov    x0, x25
    0x1010651ec <+104>: mov    x1, x24
    0x1010651f0 <+108>: mov    x2, x23
    0x1010651f4 <+112>: mov    x4, x8
    0x1010651f8 <+116>: bl     0x100f58b80               ; function signature specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Arg[1] = [Closure Propagated : reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> () to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> ()]> of generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, ()> of Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer <A> ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer<Swift.UInt8>) -> A) -> A
->  0x1010651fc <+120>: brk    #0x1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `Home` you `HomeViewController` because in your `didSelect` you are creating an new instance of that class

Comment: @zombie Yes, `Home` is `HomeViewController` in this case. Could you please explain why creating a new instance is causing a problem? I'm totally confused now. What should I try instead?